# how to know whether sms or contact is on display?

Tags: android, contacts

I am working on android application in which my service will be continuously checking whether sms or contact apps are on display or not.
can anybody help me to find out how to get know which contact or senders sms is on display.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.